# How to enable command line for Git

Tags: windows, git, github

I've just started with Git, and I can't figure out how to enable command line for Git. I see many posts suggesting the use of [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/) to enable the Git command line, and I also see many other tools that can work around it. But currently I just get the [Git client tools for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) from GitHub. Then I can use the git command in my windows command console. I don't know if it includes the `msysgit` in it.

Comment: Yes, it does include msysgit.

Comment: Thanks your clarify. I found the doc say that https://help.github.com/articles/do-i-need-to-install-anything-extra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git client tools will include msysgit. You might need to add the git bin directory into your path for ssh to work correctly with cmd (and powershell)

Also, I would highly recommend "posh git" which is a powershell module that gives you some tab completion and a git prompt in powershell, if you are a windows person, its likely you are more comfortable scripting in PS than in bash, and posh git is great for that.

find [instructions here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/13/better-git-with-powershell.aspx/) on how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

> Note on Windows usage: you should use Git with the provided msysGit
>   shell (Unix style), it allows to use the complex lines of command
>   given in this book. If you need, for some reason, to use the native
>   Windows shell / command line console, you have to use double quotes
>   instead of simple quotes (for parameters with spaces in them) and you
>   must quote the parameters ending with the circumflex accent (^) if
>   they are last on the line, as it is a continuation symbol in Windows.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Are you using the msygit shell?